# Fast http tunnel through transparent http proxy

Tags: vpn, proxy, http, openvpn, tunnel

I want to create a fast http tunnel through a very restrictive firewall (BLOXX).
As far as I know only TCP port 80 is allowed going through a transparent proxy.
Https traffic is also captured, working through BLOXX certificate.
The only other thing allowed is Skype going through a special http proxy inside the network.
Can anyone suggest some software that I can use to go through the firewall to my vps, to which http traffic is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try SoftetherVPN, it is OpenSource, uses strong encryption and is able to penetrate most firewalls. Softether also has as special option to obfuscate a VPN by using DNS or ICMP packets, this may help to bypass this firewall if everything else fails.

https://www.softether.org

Comment: I did try it. Can you suggest me some settings, because I did not manage to get it through the firewall. (No DNS or any other traffic than port 80 which goes through a transparent http proxy is allowed.)

Comment: Using the connect via http proxy option in softether client, if this proxy server is blocking SSL or changing encryption to the firewall certificate it will not work with softether. But you can try to disable the SSL encryption in softether client Properties=>AdvancedOptions so it should use only plain unencrypted connection perhaps you can get through firewall this way.